# Hide part of mesh in sculpt mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, sculpting, vertex-groups

[image]

I have this block model with a hood. I didn't think of this ahead of time. but I want to be sculpt the ears and back of the head. I can't do that with the hood in the way. I have a vertex group set up for the hood. I can hide it in edit mode fine, but it won't hide in sculpt mode. I'm aware of I can hide part of the sculpt with alt+B, but I can only do this one time. I could also separate by selection, but other than reconnecting each vertice one at a time, I'm not sure how to get it back to it's original form.

Can anyone offer any ideas?

Comment: I might just try to change the tranform of the hood and pull it way back